# Ionic header covers view content

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, web-applications, angular-ui-router

I am having trouble accommodating a header in my app. the `class="has-header"` is apparently outdated and I need help finding an alternative.
Thanks.

Feel free to correct anything else as well.

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script> 
var Hours = angular.module('Hours', ['ngRoute']);

Hours.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: '1.html',
    }).
      when('/dininghalls', {
        templateUrl: '2.html',
    }).
      when('/fitnesscenters', {
        templateUrl: '3.html'
      }).
      when('/officehours', {
        templateUrl: '4.html'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
}]);
 </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="Hours">
        <div ng-view=""></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**1.html:**

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-positive">
<div class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
  <h1 class="title">Hours</h1>
</div>
</ion-header-bar>


<ion-content>
<a href="#/4" class="button button-block button-positive">
Hours
</a>
<a href="#/2" class="button button-block button-positive">
Halls
</a>
<a href="#/3" class="button button-block button-positive">
Fitness 
</a>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: add class="has-header" to your container

Comment: thanks but I specifically said that using class="has-header" is no longer supported. Any other ideas?

Comment: why do you have a .header bar inside an ion-header-bar?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `<ion-content>` to `<ion-content class="has-header">`
........

Answer (score 0):

Add `has-header="true"` to your ion-content (looks like that may be missing from the docs?). You also shouldn't need `class="header-bar"` in your `<ion-header-bar>`.

update: 
You need to inject ionic as a dependency in your module Hours.

Comment: hey I know its been a while but i have been really busy and just tried what you said. It still does not work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: i removed class = "header-bar" and added has-header="true" to my ion content and still nothing works please help

Comment: Alright, prepare yourself for the most frustrating answer ever: you need to inject `ionic` as a dependency in your module `Hours`. Yes, it's necessary - I started a blank project, and tried it with and without that dependency, and it's definitely necessary - would have to look into the source to figure out why, but it definitely is.

Comment: Let me know if that didn't solve your problem. If it did, please accept it as the answer!

Comment: so that means 'ionic' would go right next to 'ngRoute' correct?

Comment: Thanks for sticking with the help btw

Comment: yup:
`var Hours = angular.module('Hours', ['ngRoute', 'ionic']);`

Comment: yea that didn't change it  unfortunately. Thanks for all the help but I think I'll give up on this one.